# Which descriptor implementation is correct?

Tags: python, documentation, descriptor

The following functions are listed for the Descriptor Protocol in [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#managed-attributes) section of the official Python documentation.

```py
descr.__get__(self, obj, type=None) -> value

descr.__set__(self, obj, value) -> None
    
descr.__delete__(self, obj) -> None
```

And there is an example like that in [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#managed-attributes);

```py
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

class LoggedAgeAccess:

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        value = obj._age
        logging.info('Accessing %r giving %r', 'age', value)
        return value

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        logging.info('Updating %r to %r', 'age', value)
        obj._age = value

class Person:

    age = LoggedAgeAccess()             # Descriptor instance

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name                # Regular instance attribute
        self.age = age                  # Calls __set__()

    def birthday(self):
        self.age += 1                   # Calls both __get__() and __set__()
```

However, I can implement this example using the functions of the Descriptor definition specified in [another](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors) official Python document;

```py
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

class LoggedAgeAccess:

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        value = instance._age
        logging.info('Accessing %r giving %r', 'age', value)
        return value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        logging.info('Updating %r to %r', 'age', value)
        instance._age = value

class Person:

    age = LoggedAgeAccess()             # Descriptor instance

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name                # Regular instance attribute
        self.age = age                  # Calls __set__()

    def birthday(self):
        self.age += 1                   # Calls both __get__() and __set__()
```

I couldn't figure out what was different about these documents. Which document should I refer to?

Comment: the last two examples are equals, only the choices of the identifiers in the signatures are different. One document is from the datamodel (so technical) and one from howto (so a kind of guide). what is the problem?

Comment: That's the thing, their signatures aren't the same. If the function signatures in the two documents were the same, I wouldn't be confused. Which document should I refer to?

Answer (score 1):

Both documents are correct.

The signatures are the same. The parameter names differ - but it is just that. Have in mind that Python is a dynamic typed language, and parameter names say nothing about the types that parameter should get. In your examples, `obj`, `objtype`, `instance`, `owner` are just strings as arbitrary as `foo` and `bar`.

Usually, code that create descriptors will use the `instance` and `owner` nomenclature, but that is *totally*  up to the author, and makes no difference when running the code.

Indeed, it could make a difference if these parameters where ever called with named arguments, instead of positional arguments - but the language does not do that: descriptor methods are always called with positional arguments.

Otherwise, one of the documents would simply be incorrect, and the example would not work - and a bug against the docs should be filed. But as you noticed, both work perfectly fine.